# replace a character according to its index until the word does not contain '_' in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, find

I am trying to create a function that takes a word housed in a variable and modifies it according to the letter that I am entering until the variable does not contain any '_'. The code does not give any type of error, it simply does not work even though if I try line by line if it fulfills its function. any suggestion?

```
def reveal_word():
    string = '____'
    word = 'cat'
    while '_' in string:
        letter = input('Enter your letter: ')
        for index in string:
            index = word.find(letter)
            string[index].replace('_',letter)
        return string 
print(reveal_word())
```

Comment: what do you mean it "doesnt work"?

Comment: Strings are immutable  and `str.replace()` is not in-place. You also have to assign the return value to something or it does nothing.

Comment: Did my best to translate so the question gets more answers, feel free to revert or post on https://es.stackoverflow.com/ if you have trouble getting answers here

Comment: thank you very much sometimes I forget to translate or convert the language of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample with a slightly different twist.  In this example if a character exists more than once in the word to guess, every location will be updated with that character.

```
def reveal_word():
    string = '________'
    word   = 'Hercules'
    while '_' in string:
        letter = input('Enter your letter: ')
        for index in range(0, len(string)):
            if (string[index] == '_'):
                if (word[index] == letter):
                    temp = list(string)
                    temp[index] = letter
                    string = "".join(temp)
        print('String: ', string)
    return string 
print(reveal_word())
```

Here is some terminal output.

```
Enter your letter: e
String:  _e____e_
Enter your letter: H
String:  He____e_
Enter your letter: r
String:  Her___e_
Enter your letter: c
String:  Herc__e_
Enter your letter: u
String:  Hercu_e_
Enter your letter: l
String:  Hercule_
Enter your letter: s
String:  Hercules
Hercules
```

Just another take on the puzzle.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you very much. I loved that you respected my writing format and even more so that you added the possibility of there being more than one letter within the word, a genius, thank you, really thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  I guess accommodating scenarios where a letter could be in the word more than once comes from playing Wordle.  Enjoy.

Comment: Indeed, I was looking for a way to create that part of the game code, but in my language it is called the hangman because it is supposed that for each wrong letter a rope is created that hangs a character and the idea is to guess the word to save him.
a little strange the game but that's how it was taught in my country
again thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
def reveal_word():
    word = "capybara"
    string = "_" * len(word)
    while "_" in string:
        print(string)
        char = input("Enter your letter: ")[0] # [0] to get the first letter
        idx = word.find(char)
        if idx != -1:
            word = word[:idx] + "_" + word[idx + 1 :]
            string = string[:idx] + char + string[idx + 1 :]
    return string


print(reveal_word())
```

Comment: very good answer I would have chosen it if it were not that the comment above added the function of verifying if the letter is found more than once, thank you very much friend

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat simpler solution. It uses a list of characters in the word and drops matched characters from that list until the list is empty:

```
def reveal_word():
    word = 'cat'
    string = list(word)
    
    while string:
        letter = input('Enter your letter: ')
        if letter in string:
            string = list(filter(lambda val: val !=  letter, string))

    return word 
print(reveal_word())
```

Comment: It worked for me but it does not return the word for each input of each character, also I do not know how to use lambda yet and using it without knowing how to use it feels like cheating, thanks anyway